# Sum of heights from a random point in triangle?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles

I've used an easy lemma for a problem about heights from a random point $O$ inside a equilateral triangle. It's easy to prove that $OA'+OB'+OC'=h$, where $A'$, $B'$ and $C'$ are, respectively, foots of heights from $O$ to $BC$, $AC$ and $AB$.

So I was wondering if something similar could be proven in scalene triangle. Using same notation, is it true that:
$$ OA'+OB'+OC'=\frac{h_a+h_b+h_c}3 $$

I couldn't manage to prove or counter-prove this identity.

Comment: Almost anything is a counterexample. Le't make computations easy. Our triangle is right-angled isosceles, with sides $2$, $2$, $2\sqrt{2}$. The sum of the heights is $4+2\sqrt{2}$. Let $O$ be the point where the two short legs meet. The heights are $0$, $0$, and $\sqrt{2}$. If you object that $O$ is not **inside** the triangle, pick a point very close to $O$ which **is** inside.

Comment: Sorry, typo, the heights are $2$, $2$, $\sqrt{2}$, the sum is $4+\sqrt{2}$. But it is still a counterexample.

Comment: It seems that you mean an arbitrary point, not a random point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true.

Consider O to be A, then be B. Even if you disallow O to be on the triangle, by continuity arguments, you can pick points close to A and B.